# Logical OR will not work in if statement

Tags: php, logical-operators

this is what i have:

```
<?php if($row['id']!="9") echo "style=\"display:none\""; ?>
```

simple enough, it should place `style="dsplay:none"` when 'id' is anything but 9. this does the job well, but i wanted to include 'id' 8, 12 and 13 aswell. looked simple enough, just added the logical or like this:

```
<?php if($row['id']!="8||9||12||13") echo "style=\"display:none\""; ?>
```

but it does not function anymore, so it places `style="dsplay:none"` all the time.

i wanted to go the other way around and did this

```
<?php if($row['id']=="4||5||6||11") echo "style=\"display:none\""; ?>
```

but this time around `style="dsplay:none"`was never placed.
this brought me to the conclusion that there must be something wrong with the logical or. but what is it? please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Get rid of the quote orgies. There are `'` and `"` for a reason ;)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with logical or. And there's not enough wrong with PHP for it to `eval` strings without being asked to. However, there is something wrong with your understanding of logical or.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
if($row['id']!= 8 && $row['id'] != 9 && $row['id'] != 12)
```

because the current way you are doing it is comparing the value of $`row['id']` to the string value `"8||9||12||13"`.

Or you can do something like:

```
if(in_array($row['id'], array(8, 9, 12)))
```

to condense the condition.

Comment: I think those should be && instead of || because that statement is always true...unless `$row['id']` is simultaneously equal to `"8"` `"9"`  and `"12"`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it like that.

Either use `if($row['id'] == 4 || $row['id'] == 5 || ...)` or use `in_array()`: `if(in_array($row['id'], array(4,5,6,11)))`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to write

```
<?php if(in_array($row['id'], array(8, 9, 12, 13)) /* ... */; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing numbers with strings in a way that won't work. E.g. an `$row['id']` of `1` is not equal to the string `"4||5||6||11"`.

You could use the [`in_array`](http://php.net/in-array) function which checks whether a value exist in an array:

```
if(!in_array($row['id'], array(4, 5, 6, 11)) echo ' style="display:none"';
```

Logical OR's (`||`) do not work inside strings.

Answer (score 0):

That's not logical or, that's a string literal. But [De Morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
if(($row['id']!="8") && $row['id']!="9" && ...
```